# How C++ alias works?

Tags: c++, alias, compiler-optimization

How does alias internally work in C++?
Does it allocate its own memory like pointers?
Otherwise how does the compiler treat it?
Is it like C++ Macro preprocessor computing?

```
int x=5;
int &y=x; //Assembly of this???
```

Comment: That is a C++ only feature, C does not have reference types

Comment: These are called references. And they don't exist in C.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it

Comment: How it works is implementation-dependent. Also, reference variables are probably implemented differently from reference parameters to functions, since the latter change from one call to the next.

Comment: The best way for you to understand it is to see it with your own eyes. In many debuggers (including visual studio), when you hit a breakpoint,  you can turn on the "view assembly" view where you can see the assembly code.

Comment: You can also use godbolt.org to see the assembly.

Comment: A local reference is probably like a macro, the compiler just translates it automatically. A reference parameter is probably implemented as a hidden pointer.

Comment: The compiler can choose from many ways to implement it.  In your example, there is [probably **no assembly** generated](https://godbolt.org/z/en91xb7Ex).  `y` is simply another way to type `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called *references*.

The standard doesn't describe how they (or anything else) work on the assembly level.

In practice, they are implemented as pointers, unless the compiler optimizes them away (which is easier for references compared to pointers, because they can't be reassigned).

They are unrelated to macros, the preprocessor doesn't know about references.

The standard contains some interesting wording for references: they "are not objects", the consequence being that you can't legally meaningfully examine their memory layout and modify it. But this is mostly a peculiarity of the wording; for most purposes they work like immutable pointers.